# How to programmatically set a Retention Label on an email in M365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is it possible to set a Retention Label or Retention Policy on a mail item? Can it be done through MS Graph? If not, can it be done any other way? I can see that the Outlook Web App can set a retention label.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to stamp a retention tag on a item using singlevalueextendedproperties (eg [Retrieve SingleValueExtendedProperties with MS-Graph API created with EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621446/retrieve-singlevalueextendedproperties-with-ms-graph-api-created-with-ews)) like you could in EWS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/akashb/stamping-retention-policy-tag-using-ews-managed-api-1-1-from-powershellexchange-2010 (One note is ComplianceTags are new feature since the old EWS method)